# Does Xcode 4.1 support git?

Tags: xcode, git

In [this announce](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) Apple says that Xcode 4 support Git. But in my SCM configuration I couldn't find Git option and see only: CVS, Perforce and Subversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article solves your dilemma: [clicky](http://www.24100.net/2010/06/no-repository-type-git-in-xcode-4-developer-preview-here-is-the-solution/).

EDIT: The article mentioned placing a git binary (or symlink) in /usr/bin should mean the git option now shows in the SCM menu.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 does not support cvs or Perforce. If you're seeing either of those, you're running Xcode 3 (presumably with a iOS 4.x SDK), not Xcode 4.